# Riddle - three lines are crossing here!

Tags: riddle

> You can eat me,
>   You can use me,
>   You can listen to me,
>   You can visit me,
>   It is possible to do all of that at the same time
>   But it is highly improbable.
>
> Sometimes I am filled with rats,
>   Sometimes I am filled with people,
>   Sometimes I am filled with bees,
>   Sometimes I am filled with bugs,
>   But never at the same time
>   Or you'll have a bad time.

What am I?

#### Edit 1:

Since there is a lot of answer but no one find it, I give you a hint

> Rats, people, bees and bugs are not animals. But people are still humans.

#### Edit 2:

Here is a new hint

> I am layered when you eat me,
>  I am tabbed when you use me,
>  I am played when you listen to me,
>  I am opened when you visit me.

#### Edit 3:

There is some answers that match one of the clues but they are not answers.

> Cake is valid for the "You can eat me" clue. I am looking for a cake name.
>  House is valid for the "You can visit me" clue. I am looking for a type of house.
>  Subway is valid for the "three lines are crossing here" clue.

With that being said, I think I almost give you the answer.

It looks like my second riddle is far harder than my first one. I hope you guys enjoyed it anyway.

Comment: Is it earth????

Comment: I'm afraid It's not  :)

Comment: is it a Restaurant :)

Comment: No it's not. You'll have to continue your quest :)

Comment: ok may be last try....is it Home Sweet Home :)

Comment: Still not the expected answer.

Comment: @user2408578 Please refrain from posting answers in the comments. Instead, post an answer. The comments are for asking clarifying questions or adding other commentary that might be useful to other people.

Comment: Do you mean "filled by" or "filled with"? The first means that the rats, people, etc fill <the answer> with something; the second means that the rats, people, etc are stuffed into <the answer>.

Comment: I mean "with" thank you for your comment. I hope there is not too many approximations. English is my second language.

Comment: In your hint you state Rats are not animals... but Rats ARE animals... Mammals in the Animalia Kingdom... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat I'm confused.

Comment: I know that rats are animals, but in this riddle, they are not. If I tell you more, I will solve the riddle for you. But in the end, you'll understand the rats I am using

Comment: Is it possible, in the context of this riddle, to replace the word 'eat' with the word 'consume'?

Comment: @tfitzger why not? But here it really means eat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest clue:

> Opera

Three lines are crossing here

> The Opera subway station of the Paris Metro

You can eat me,

> Opera cake (layered)

You can use me,

> Opera browser (tabbed)

You can listen to me,

> Opera music (played)

You can visit me,

> Opera house (opened)

It is possible to do all of that at the same time
But it is highly improbable.

Sometimes I am filled with rats,

> "Opera rats", nickname for young ballet students at the Paris Opera

Sometimes I am filled with people,

> Opera house is filled with people

Sometimes I am filled with bees,

> New guess: The musical note "B"
>
>  Wrong guesses so far:
>  Guess 1: "Flight of the Bumblebee"
>  Guess 2: Bees on top of the Paris Opera? [this?](http://www.picturetank.com/___/series/b773991aac75a12c6b8dafb20e716a70/Bees_in_Paris.html)
>  Guess 3: "Bis" meaning a musical encore
>  Guess 4: The B&B Opera in Paris (bed and breakfast)
>  Guess 5: "The British Opera" song by the Bee Gees
>  Guess 6: The "buzz" at the opera.

Sometimes I am filled with bugs,

> Software bugs in the Opera browser (thanks @tfitzger).

But never at the same time
Or you'll have a bad time.

Comment: Bugs could also be software bugs in the Opera browser.

Comment: @tfitzger True, I never used the Opera browser myself so I wouldn't know if it had a reputation for being buggy.

Comment: @JS1 you almost have every thing right. The clues with rats and bees are not correct. Could you correct them?

Comment: @JS1 the bugs suggested by tfitzger is the correct answer

Comment: @JS1 you got the rats correct. For the bees, just say it out loud without thinking of the spelling I used. This one is kind of a strech :)

Comment: @JS1 you're doing well so far, but still not the bees.

Comment: @A.D. How about now?

Comment: @JS1 good job, you made it :)

Comment: @A.D. This is probably easier for someone in France.  Americans (like me) aren't familiar with opera cake, opera rats, or the Metro lines.  But the other clues were familiar.

Comment: @JS1 You're right. My last riddle was so easy that I decided to make it a little bit harder. Too hard it seems.

Answer (score 10):

My guess is:

> **Space**
>  
> You can eat up (waste) Space
>  
>  You can use Space
>  
>  You can listen to space (radio telescope)
>  
>  You can visit space (Astronauts)

it's possible to do them all simultaneously, though unlikely

> Space can be filled with rats, people, bees, and/or bugs,
>  
>  but if they're filling the same space at the same time it will be bad
>  
> And Finally, a mathematical "space" occupies three dimensions (x,y,z axis) all of which converge at an origin... three lines crossing

Comment: Nice! but that's not it.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Mark! Thanks for taking the time to create a proper answer to the question. It is suggested that you use the spoiler tags in your answer ">!" to cover up your answer. I can edit your answer once you are finished to show you as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the assist there Mark N :) is there an option for an "in-line" spoiler, or can it only cover entire lines/blocks?

Comment: @Mark only lines and blocks AFAIK

Answer (score 9):

> **House** 
>  
>  You can eat a gingerbread house, use a house to live in, listen to house music, and visit your friends' houses. You can also eat a gingerbread house and listen to house music while living in your friend's house, but that's not a likely scenario. 
>  
>  Rats, bugs, and people all live in houses. And bees live in bee houses, which are used like hives by beekeepers.

Comment: I don't think I'm right, however. if it was house then I'd imagine doghouses and birdhouses would be mentioned in the riddle instead of rats and bugs, which doesn't quite fit the answer.

Comment: @JLee an edge of a Monopoly board maybe?

Comment: Oh wait, I've a better idea. A triangle is house shaped, and it's made of three lines that cross on each end

Comment: I like your answer, but that's not it. It has to match the title as well.

Comment: @A.D. The answer crosses 3 lines of thinking (thinking of a house as physical location, music, and food), technically fulfilling all the criteria.

Comment: @n00b actually, it's 4 because you forget the one you can use

Answer (score 3):

My answer is

> Palm (both tree and hand)

You can eat the heart

You can use it to cultivate coconuts

You can listen to them when the wind is blowing

You can visit it, preferably at the beach

To do all of this at the same time is unlikely.

Bees, bugs, people and rats can climb it, but as far as the hand is concerned you will have a bad time if it is filled by all of them.

Finally, three lines are crossing it if you look at it (the one in your hand).

Comment: That's not it but I like it

Comment: No way! I was sure I had it!

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you

Answer (score 3):

First guess:

> Viruses

You can eat me,

> In the biological sense, you can eat a virus if it is in something like, say, chicken

You can use me,

> Both in the biological and technological senses, you can use a virus for personal gain

You can listen to me,

> More in the technological sense, it is possible for a virus to create a sound

You can visit me,

> Web based viruses...

It is possible to do all of that at the same time

> You could be eating a contaminated chicken sandwich while visiting a site with a virus...

Sometimes I am filled with rats,

> Ghost RAT is a virus. In a more basic sense, RATs (Remote Admin Tools) help viruses get along systems

Sometimes I am filled with people,

> It is possible for a virus to be passing along photos of humans...

Sometimes I am filled with bees,

> VisualBee is a virus toolbar

Sometimes I am filled with bugs,

> Computer viruses can 'bug' systems to gain information, or have faulty software

But never at the same time

Or you'll have a bad time.

> If you have all of these, you have quite a bit of viruses.

As for the title

> The basic image for a virus is three crossed lines: https://landofthebluemoon.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/logo-virus.png

Comment: Nice work but that's not it

Comment: @A.D. Drat. Ah well, back to the drawing board. Was I at least in the right direction?

Comment: There is one thing you got right. It's the bug clue.

Comment: @A.D. Ok. Quick question: are the three lines referring to actual lines, or is it a way of saying that the answer can be interpreted in multiple ways?

Comment: yes but not in a geometric context

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is:

> A subway.

It seems to fit the title as well.

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Hey, Pun! Welcome to Puzzling.SE. It's typically best to explain your answers to the questions fairly thoroughly, so that the asker can understand your intentions and other people can draw off of your ideas to help solve the puzzle if your answer is incorrect. :)

Answer (score 2):

(Similar to MisterEman22) I don't think it's correct, but it matches most of the parts. Is it:

> chips

You can eat me,

> Potato chips

You can use me,

> wood chips

You can listen to me,

> Chip tunes (a type of music)

You can visit me,

> chips of land (or islands)

It is possible to do all of that at the same time
But it is highly improbable.

> I don't think you will be eating chips on an island while using wood chips and listening to chip tunes.

Sometimes I am filled with rats,

Sometimes I am filled with people,

Sometimes I am filled with bees,

Sometimes I am filled with bugs,

But never at the same time

Or you'll have a bad time.

> I guess chips of land (or islands) can be full of all of these, but if it was 'full' with 4 different things, that wouldn't be very nice.
>  
>  Or possibly computer chips can have bugs, RATs and AI/software (made by/of people) in them and as for bee's maybe an annoying buzz ;)

Comment: Nice try, still not the valid option. I think I'll add an other clue

Answer (score 2):

Answer

> cake

You can eat me,

> obvious (and layered)

You can use me,

> Guitar tabs for music by Cake (the band).  A bit of a stretch, I think.

You can listen to me,

> Music by Cake

You can visit me,

> Not sure, but maybe a festival of some kind about cake (which has to be opened)

It is possible to do all of that at the same time
 But it is highly improbable.

> Visiting the festival (or whatever) while listening to Cake, playing along on the guitar, and eating cake?

Sometimes I am filled with rats,

> Rat found in a birthday cake (February 2014).

Sometimes I am filled with people,

> Giant cake that someone jumps out of.

Sometimes I am filled with bees,

> Honeycomb can be called cake.

Sometimes I am filled with bugs,

> Several software products (having software bugs) with Cake in the name (including CakeWalk, which is used for sound editing, providing another way to hear the cake).

But never at the same time
 Or you'll have a bad time.

> Not sure if there's something being missed here.

Three lines are crossing here!

> Not sure how to tie this in, but may be related to the layers or how it is cut (three cuts results in six slices).

Comment: That's not the answer. But you have few clues correct.

Answer (score 2):

Webpages (because some of your clues: tabbed, played, layered (assuming eat means consume as in consume content), played, and opened all sound like they're describing a browser/webpage), surfaces (including screens: render with scanLINES, can be layered, tabbed, et cetera), rails (playing with alternative ideas of lines and intersections), data (various computer terms), and streams (as in both social streams and literal streams of water) are all ones I considered but I think my best guess is: "text".

"Text" because:

Lines as in a play,

Layered when ate as in that the text is dense (layered) with subtext when read/consumed (ate),

Text can be tabbed as in indented, or (more likely) split into partial segments when created/edited (used).

You can hear text read aloud (or played from an audio file),

You open a book or webpage to see (visit) text,

Rat as in despicable characters,

People being discussed,

Bees could mean literal bees are being describe or because the text 
contains a lot of "buzz words",

Bugs could mean grammatical errors or inaccurate information being presented in the text.

Grammatical errors, buzz words, and rats would make an unpleasant read in my opinion.

I hope you like this guess; if it's wrong, could you give a bit more of a hint by what you by "crossing" or what you meant when you said: "yes [referring to lines meaning actual lines] but not in a geometric context"

Comment: Also text can be tabbed as in indented (sorry, I forgot to add this earlier).

Comment: Look at the comments on the question. I asked about `eat` vs. `consumed`. Response: "why not? But here it really means eat."

Comment: Hello, tfitzger. Yes, sadly I didn't notice that comment until after I posted my response though I would still argue that text can still be eaten (as in ingested) in some contexts such as writing on a cake (which is layered); though I know cake, and text, are probably not the answer A.D. was looking for. I do hope for some more information about the three lines "crossing".

Comment: Yeah, that's what's getting me caught up...

Comment: @Anadian that's not webpages. I will add more clues

Answer (score 1):

You may be a

> nest

You can eat me,

> There is something called an [edible bird's nest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edible_bird%27s_nest).

You can use me,

> You can use the [nest](https://nest.com/) thermostat.

You can listen to me,

> You can listen to the [Nest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nest_%28band%29) band.

You can visit me,

> You can always walk up to an animal's/insect's nest.

Sometimes I am filled with rats,

> Rats can build nests.

Sometimes I am filled with people,

> The [Bird's Nest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing_National_Stadium) stadium in Beijing.

Sometimes I am filled with bees,

> A beehive is a nest.

Sometimes I am filled with bugs,

> Bugs can build nests.

Comment: Really nice use of the hints. But that's not a nest. And you forgot to match it to the title.

Answer (score 1):

What about a...

> Tree?

You can eat me,

> Apples and other fruits which grow on trees

You can use me,

> Harvesting and processing wood to build a house

You can listen to me,

> Musical instruments made of wood

You can visit me,

> Resting on a branch. Also, possibly treehouses?

It is possible to do all of that at the same time

> Eating an apple in a tree branch while listening to a performer play a wooden instrument

But it is highly improbable.

> Self-explanatory

Sometimes I am filled with rats,

> Some species of rats nest in trees

Sometimes I am filled with people,

> People in houses?

Sometimes I am filled with bees,

> Beehives

Sometimes I am filled with bugs,

> Termites and such nesting in trees

But never at the same time Or you'll have a bad time

> Bees and termites nesting in wooden buildings can potentially be dangerous

Comment: That's not it. It does not match neither the title nor the hints

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a

> FLOWER

You can eat me,

> Cauliflower ;-)

You can use me,

> to make a garland

You can listen to me,

> Need a proper device to listen literally

You can visit me,

> In the garden

It is possible to do all of that at the same time
But it is highly improbable.

> It is a paradox.

Sometimes I am filled with rats,

> If it is around

Sometimes I am filled with people,

> Empty Trash Bins are sometimes used by Homeless to shield from rain.

Sometimes I am filled with bees,

> Why only Homeless ? Why not Birds and Bees?

Sometimes I am filled with bugs,

> Of course

But never at the same time
Or you'll have a bad time.

> Hmmm.... i guess.

Comment: That's not it. The title is not a bait :)

Comment: @A.D. I think I know the answer now. Am revising it.

Comment: Still not the correct answer

Comment: @A.D. Thanks for being on top so quick.

Answer (score 0):

My guess, Its

> **ATTIC**

You can eat me,

> Well !!! can not fit the first line.. Shame :(

You can use me,

> We all use it to put stuff in there.

You can listen to me,

> May be refers to some bands, named The Attic or Attic Music

You can visit me,

> To keep stuff.

It is possible to do all of that at the same time

> We can eat(don't know what :p), use, visit and listen to Attic

But it is highly improbable.

> Who does that ??

Sometimes I am filled with rats,
Sometimes I am filled with people,
Sometimes I am filled with bees,
Sometimes I am filled with bugs,

> Are filled with rats, people, bees and bugs. ([link](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2458499/Pest-controllers-30-000-bees-dozens-squirrels-rats-feeding-honeycomb-attic-woman-98-oblivious-noise.html))

But never at the same time
Or you'll have a bad time.

> Bad Idea [Link](http://gawker.com/man-killed-by-800-000-bees-hiding-in-the-attic-1644108689)

**Title**
Three lines are crossing here!

> Because of triangular shape

Comment: That second link, though. D:

Comment: That's not it. Nice try

Answer (score 0):

My guess is:

> Computer memory (or something similar)

You can eat me,

> You can "eat up" memory

You can use me,

> You can obviously use the memory

You can listen to me,

> If its an audio file you can listen to it

You can visit me,

> You can visit the file's location in a browser

It is possible to do all of that at the same time
But it is highly improbable.

> You could do all at the same time, but your computer might run slow

Sometimes I am filled with rats,

> A type of virus

Sometimes I am filled with people,

> Multiple people accessing something, or multiple users

Sometimes I am filled with bees,

> Not sure about this one..

Sometimes I am filled with bugs,

> There can be bugs in the computer

But never at the same time
Or you'll have a bad time.

> It's not good if a computer has bugs or viruses on it while people are using it

Comment: You are right for the bugs. But that's not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @A.D. is bugs the only part of mine that's right?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. But check the hints. They might help you

Answer (score 0):

I think it's:

> Apple

```
You can eat me,
```

> You can eat an apple

```
You can use me,
```

> MAC product

```
You can listen to me,
```

> Itunes

```
You can visit me,
```

> Apple Store

```
It is possible to do all of that at the same time
But it is highly improbable.

Sometimes I am filled with rats,
```

> This one i dont get (Maybe the company being filled with rats?)

```
Sometimes I am filled with people,
```

> Apple store can be filled with people

```
Sometimes I am filled with bees,
```

> I'm guessing the buzz through earphones while listening to your ipod.

```
Sometimes I am filled with bugs,
```

> Iphone or Laptop

```
But never at the same time
Or you'll have a bad time.

I am layered when you eat me,
```

> Apple cake??? Not sure all of a sudden

```
I am tabbed when you use me,
```

> Apple laptop(mac) browser tabs or whatever other apple software with tabs etc...

```
I am played when you listen to me,
```

> Itunes

```
I am opened when you visit me.
```

> Apple store

Comment: Nice but that's not it.